# Change the value of a mat-slider element with Angular5

Tags: material-design, angular5

I have multiple mat-slider elements in my template and i want to change the value of a specific slider. I know how to do it with `MatRadioButton` and other Material design components but it looks like mat-slider doesn't offer the option to get the id of a specific mat-slider and change his value !!

With `MatRadioButton` i can do this

```
@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton) rbuttons;
this.rbuttons.filter(x => x.id == "cars" + id)[0].checked = true;// Works
```

But how to change the value of a mat-slider element since i cannot filter by id with mat-slider ? What i want to do is something like this :

```
 @ViewChildren(MatSlider) sliders;
 this.sliders.filter(x => x.id == "cars" + id)[0].value= 2; // Not working since i cannot filter by Id like i do with MatRadioButton
```

Template :

```
<mat-slider min="0" max="2" step="1" value="2" (change)="changeCar(id)" id="car{{id}}"></mat-slider>
<mat-slider min="0" max="2" step="1" value="0" (change)="changeCar(id)" id="car{{id}}"></mat-slider>
```

So let say if i change the first slider having the id = car34 and value 2, i want to update the second slider with id = car35 and put value = 2 instead of 0.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just append your own ID to each slider?

Comment: What do you mean ? I updated my post adding the code template